# Android Spinner for filtering data

Tags: android, view, spinner

I know this is possible but I'm just wondering if anyone else has done it or anyone's opinions on what the best method for implementing this is. Basically I have a spinner which will be populated from a column in a database table. I want to be able to select the data item and for it to display all of the other items that have that same value.

e.g.

Employee has a department, dropdown has the departments in and when a department is chosen it displays all of the employees in that department.

I have the spinner populating with the correct data so don't need advice on this part.

If you need any more information then please ask.

Comment: So you haven't tried anything yet, right?

Comment: No, at this stage I'm just wondering what the best method to go about it is as I'm still not overly familiar with Android - so I wanted to get others opinions or experiences on doing something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Expandable list for this..

Set Department as Parent and Employees as Child..

For reference check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)..

In API demos you can find the examples for Expandable list check [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html), [also this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html) ,   [and this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html)